# Socket is emiting too many times, can't close it Angular

Tags: angular, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io to send messages between users in a chat module on my website.

The messages go through fine but the behavior is strange, it is coming from the way I translated the socket.io's jquery documentation into javascript.

The first is sent once.
The second goes fine.
The third two times.
The fourth three times.
etc..

For example if I type: `foo, void, int, double` this is displayed:

foo

void

void

int

int

int

double

double

double

double

Here is my code so far:

`html`:

```
<form action="" [formGroup]="messageForm" (ngSubmit)="sendMessage()">
  <input id="message" formControlName="message" #message class="form-control" class="messageInput" autocomplete="off"/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">SEND</button>
</form>
```

`sendMessage() called from html`:

```
sendMessage() {
  if (this.messageForm.valid) {
    this.message = this.messageForm.get('message').value;
    this.messageForm.reset();
    this.socket.emit('chat message', this.message);
    this.socket.on('chat message', this.receive);
  }
}

receive = function(msg) {
  console.log('receive called'); // called incrementally over time, 1, 22, 333 etc..
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  document.getElementById('messageList').appendChild(li);
  li.innerHTML = msg;
};
```

`backend`:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    });
   socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
   });
 });
```

`Here is the socket.io tutorial code for reference`:

```
$(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
         return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
});
```

After doing some research and 'console.logging' everywhere it looks like `receive()` is called exponentially, one time the first message, two times the second message etc.. I believe I am missing the correct translation to the `return false` from the socket.io jquery's code into my Angular adaptation..

What can I do?

Comment: Anyone can help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

`this.socket.on('chat message', this.receive);` should not be inside the `sendMessage()` function. It lives in the socket initalization to be declared once:

```
try {
    this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    this.socket.on('chat message', this.receive);
  } catch (e) {
      console.log('Could not connect socket.io');
  }
```